# Ho to prevent @Transactional to close transaction if new thread started inside annotated method?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

Having a following service implementation:

```
@Transactional
   public Void process(Data data)
   {
      ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
      Connection connection = HibernateUtil.getConnection(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession());
      future = executorService.submit(new ProcessJob(connection));
      return null;
   }
```

Thread starts successfully but it fails soon with an exception:

> connnection proxy not usable after transaction  completionorg.hibernate.jdbc.BorrowedConnectionProxy.invoke(BorrowedConnectionProxy.java:42)

Is there any way to prevent closing a transaction until started thread is finished?

Comment: You shouldn't share a connection or transaction between threads. Also if you need to wait (because that is what you end up doing eventually) what is the purpose of the async stuff. Also your code also looks like you are working around Spring and Hibernate, creating your own threads and as well are keeping state in a singleton al things you shouldn't be doing at all.

Comment: If you get another connection using sessionFactory.openSession() instead of sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(), may solve your problem.